# How can i access my bitcoin core payment if headers cannot sync due to insufficient storage

Tags: bitcoin-core

My Mac laptop does not have enough storage to sync more than 51.57% of headers needed and i cannot access my bitcoin payment. I have tried creating space, trying to change data directory and importing my bitcoin core wallet online. The Bitcoin core app now closes immediately after opening due to my disk almost full.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to reduce storage with pruning mode?
https://bitcoin.org/en/full-node#reduce-storage

Comment: I am confused on how to do so exactly. I tried inputting prune commands in the console but all i got was errors

Comment: @AlexSalsa I put prune=550 to the bitcoin.conf file, Bitcoin core takes about 2GB on my PC

Comment: what exactly would you write because it always says error  maybe it is different for mac?

Comment: i tried a youtube video and it seems to be working. thankyou for now  if it screws up i will be back

Answer (score 0):

You could add storage ,flash drive or external hard drive and run Bitcoin core app  from it instead.(after being installed on it)